# Fatal application error not caught by MadExcept

Tags: delphi, error-handling

I have an application which runs multiple threads. I use MadExcept to catch errors and debug it.

The problem is that sometimes after 2-3 hours of running,  Windows shows a close program dialog. Why isn't that error handled by MadExcept ?

Comment: If the error is happening outside Delphi's exception logic, and outside the things that MadExcept can catch, there's nothing MadExcept can do. However, you've given no information about the actual error ("a close program dialog" doesn't help). If it's the close dialog I **think** it might be (but am  not sure, because you didn't say what version of Windows either), there's a way to see the error report and stack trace that you can use to see what error is actually happening and where; I can't see it from here, though, so I can't be of much more help. :)

Comment: I am using Windows 7 there is no more information provided just that : " Program has encountered an error and windows ... "

Comment: There are links on that dialog to view the error report, which reveal  the path and name of the text file that will be sent to MS if you allow it to send the bug report. Inside that text file is the call stack and other info (exception code, register content, instruction pointer info, etc.) that can help figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are a special case. If you have an exception in a thread, it will not get handled by the global handler, and will usually kill your application. The solution is easy though, with madExcept. Just catch the exception, and tell MadExcept about it. It will log in the usual way, and you won't kill your thread.

```
uses 
{$IFDEF MadExcept}
 madExcept,
{$ENDIF}


procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  try
      SetName;
    // do your stuff

  except
    on errInfo : Exception do
    begin
{$IFDEF MadExcept}
      HandleException(etNormal, errInfo);
{$ENDIF}
    end;
  end;
end;
```

What I also do is have the thread set a "RunningOK" property to true when it starts, and the exception sets it to False. This way my control code can see that something went wrong, and handle that appropriately (either restart it, or report the error, etc)

Comment: @David Sorry, don't follow? If you want to compile without madExcept, this allows you to do so. The HandleException is madExcept specific, so obviously needs to be ignored if you don't have it. But it also means that you can get a trace of the exception in the normal madExcept way.

Comment: Maybe that's new then, because this is how Mathias said I should do this when I was wanting to grab the exception details.